# as.Date returns number when working with Shiny

Tags: r, date, shiny, as.date

I'm working with google forms to create a subscription form. As the "date" type question used in google forms is a bit confusing for people with little contact with technology (the people that are going to subscribe are at-risk teenagers), I chose to separate year, month and day of birth in three different questions and then unite then using as.Date. I would upload the .csv file generated by google forms using fileInput and renderTable to show the data.

This code works perfectly in the console

```
# read the file from my computer
df <- read_csv("~APAMI/R/base.csv")
    colnames(df)<- c("day", "month", "year")
    dn <- as.Date(with(df, paste("year", "month", "day",sep="-")), "%Y-%m-%d")
    df$dn<-dn
    df
```

But when I apply this code to shiny the date returns a number, not the date.
I've tried to use lubridate and to use "as.character" instead of "paste" .  I've tried to use the "origin" function in as.Date, as well as the POSIXc option. Got the same result.

I really can't use the "date" question in forms, because people are having a hard time filling the questionnaire and are putting the wrong birth date constantly.

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(date)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Triagem da Inscrição para APAMI"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('datafile', 'Base de Dados')
    ),

    mainPanel(
       tableOutput("tabela")
    )
  )
))
```

SERVER

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(date)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$tabela <- renderTable ({

    inFile <- input$datafile 

    if(is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    df <- read_csv(inFile$datapath)
    colnames(df)<- c("year", "month", "day")
    dn <- as.Date(with(df, paste(year, month, day,sep="-")), "%Y-%m-%d")
    df$dn<-dn
    df
  })
})
```

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R shiny different output between renderTable and renderDataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548843/r-shiny-different-output-between-rendertable-and-renderdatatable)

Comment: It is a known issue with `renderTable` https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/129 . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548843/r-shiny-different-output-between-rendertable-and-renderdatatable for a workaround

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the function "strftime".  By the way, I used "read.csv" instead of "read_csv", because I got an error when running your code.

```
dn <- strftime(paste(df$year, df$month, df$day,sep="-"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```