# Shiny Dashboard Date Slider Input

Tags: r, date, shiny, slider

I am new to R and Shiny and have a problem that I have not been able to solve for hours.

I have a dataset from which I display the daily consumption of coffee on a dashboard, which works very well. The plot is a ggplot geom_line chart.

But now I want to be able to change the time period with two sliders.
The sliders I have also managed to do, but the plot does not change when the slider is moved.

I also suspect that I have an error with the date format.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for the help

[RawData Dataset](https://github.com/Skruff80/Getting-started/blob/master/Dataset/ProductList.csv)

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Coffee consumption"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("DatesMerge",
                  "Dates:",
                  min = as.Date("2018-01-22","%Y-%m-%d"),
                  max = as.Date("2020-04-04","%Y-%m-%d"),
                  value= c(as.Date("2018-01-22","%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-04-04","%Y-%m-%d")),
                  timeFormat="%Y-%m-%d")
    ),
    mainPanel(

      plotOutput("plot_daycount"),
      tableOutput("structure"),
      tableOutput("rawdata"),
      tableOutput("dayconsumption")) 

  )
)
)


# RawData import

coffeedata = fread("C:/temp/ProductList.csv")

setDF(coffeedata)

coffeedata$Date = as.Date(coffeedata$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")

# Products a day counter
countcoffee <- function(timeStamps) {
  Dates <- as.Date(strftime(coffeedata$Date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
  allDates <- seq(from = min(Dates), to = max(Dates), by = "day")
  coffee.count <- sapply(allDates, FUN = function(X) sum(Dates == X))
  data.frame(day = allDates, coffee.count = coffee.count)}

# Making a DF with day consumption
daylicounter = countcoffee(df$coffee.date)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$structure = renderPrint({
    str(coffeedata)
  })

  # Raw Data
  output$rawdata = renderTable({
    head(coffeedata)
  })

  output$dayconsumption = renderTable({
    head(daylicounter)
  })


  # GGPLOT2
  output$plot_daycount = renderPlot({

    DatesMerge = input$DatesMerge

    ggplot(daylicounter[daylicounter == DatesMerge], aes(daylicounter$day, daylicounter$coffee.count)) + 
           geom_line(color = "orange", size = 1) 
           scale_x_date(breaks = "3 month", 
                       date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y")


# Try outs    
#   ggplot(daylicounter[month(day) == month(DatesMerge)], mapping = aes(day = day)) + 
#      geom_line(color = "orange", size = 1) 
#      scale_x_date(breaks = "3 month", 
#                  date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y")
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: If you have additional comments/questions, feel free to use comments section (or post new question on SO) rather than adding an answer. See my edited answer in regards to your last question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @Kevin, you need to use `input$DatesMerge[1]` and `input$DatesMerge[2]` when subsetting your data. For clarity, this can be done in a separate step. Try something like this in your server:

```
output$plot_daycount = renderPlot({
  DatesMerge <- as.Date(input$DatesMerge, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
  sub_data <- subset(daylicounter, day >= DatesMerge[1] & day <= DatesMerge[2])
  ggplot(sub_data, aes(x = day, y = coffee.count)) + 
    geom_line(color = "orange", size = 1) +
    scale_x_date(breaks = "3 month", date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y")
})
```

**Edit** Additional question from OP was asked:

> Why does my date format look normal with str(coffeedata) but with
>   head(coffeedata) the date is just a number?

`renderTable` uses `xtable` which may have trouble with dates. You can get your dates to display correctly by converting to character first (one option):

```
output$rawdata = renderTable({
  coffeedata$Date <- as.character(coffeedata$Date)
  head(coffeedata)
})

output$dayconsumption = renderTable({
  daylicounter$day <- as.character(daylicounter$day)
  head(daylicounter)
})
```

See other questions on this topic:

[as.Date returns number when working with Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414187/as-date-returns-number-when-working-with-shiny)

[R shiny different output between renderTable and renderDataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548843/r-shiny-different-output-between-rendertable-and-renderdatatable)

Comment: It's working!! Thanks a lot @Ben & @Kevin! Amazing community! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to R and Shiny, you are off to a great start. Few things:

1. I don't recommend you using `=` in shiny, majority of the cases you want to use `<-`
2. To simplify code, no reason to add a variable like `DatesMerge`. It adds no value (at least in the code above)
3. For a dual slider, you need to tell shiny which end to pick. `input$DatesMerge` doesn't mean anything but `input$DatesMerge[1]` does.
4. When asking for help, it is always better to add a subset of data within the code itself. You tend to get more help and it is easier to run for the person trying to help (like me I was too lazy to download the file and place it in a folder so I didn't run it)

You need to account for a range of dates in your slider when subsetting the data; you also for the `,` when subsetting the data.

```
ggplot(daylicounter[daylicounter %in% input$DatesMerge[1]:input$DatesMerge[2],], aes(daylicounter$day, daylicounter$coffee.count)) + 
       geom_line(color = "orange", size = 1) +
       scale_x_date(breaks = "3 month", 
                   date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y")
```